# MongoDB: Sort by field existing and then alphabetically

Tags: mongodb

In my database I have a field of `name`. In some records it is an empty string, in others it has a name in it.

In my query, I'm currently doing:

```
db.users.find({}).sort({'name': 1})
```

However, this returns results with an empty name field first, then alphabetically returns results. As expected, doing `.sort({'name': -1})` returns results with a name and then results with an empty string, but it's in reverse-alphabetical order.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this type of sorting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```js
db.users.find({ "name": { "$exists": true } }).sort({'name': 1})
```

Because after all when a field you want to sort on is not actually present then the returned value is `null` and therefor "lower" in the order than any positive result. So it makes sense to exclude those results if you really are only looking for something with a matching value.

If you really want all the results in there and regarless of a `null` content, then I suggest you "weight" them via `.aggregate()`:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
     { "$project": {
         "name": 1,
         "score": {
             "$cond": [
                 { "$ifNull": [ "$name", false ] },
                 1,
                 10
             ]
         }
     }},
     { "$sort": { "score": 1, "name": 1 } }
])
```

And that moves all `null` results to the "end of the chain" by assigning a value as such.

Comment: In the end I decided to go back into my DB creation scrips and add a manual "scoring" as each doc is created (giving me more control over different parameters), but this solution worked too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter out documents with an empty `"name"` field, change your query: `db.users.find({"name": {"$ne": ""}}).sort({"name": 1})`