# MongoDB sort by only exists entry, key with value first and key with null or not exists last

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have a collection of 15000 documents. Some documents have **`sr_no`** with numeric values and other with absent of **`sr_no`**.

Now i want to get entries like all documents comes first which has **`sr_no`** with **asc** then all others.

I tried **`.find().sort({sr_no:1})`** but it return all **`null`** entries first then **asc** with **`sr_no`**.

> This question seems too close with [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680809/mongodb-sort-by-field-existing-and-then-alphabetically). But slightly defer
>   with numeric key.

**I answered it with hack below.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Sort by field existing and then alphabetically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680809/mongodb-sort-by-field-existing-and-then-alphabetically)

Comment: @BlakesSeven My que is lil closer.

Comment: I don't think that *"Store something else"* really answers the question as you posed it. The answer to actually sorting `null` or missing last is to project a value greater than the expected values to sort. It's also not true if the data was "string" based as it was in the mentioned duplicate. Therefore I don't think what you call a "solution" really is one.

Comment: Its not solution, its a hack. still finding solution.

Comment: Why did you self answer, if you are asking for an answer? The solution is therefore in the marked duplicate. You need to "weight" the `null` values ( which is what a non-existent key actually is ) with a value larger than what you are sorting on so they appear at the end. That's what the answer says, and since I wrote it then I should know. Like I said, actually writing data into the key is not the same as weighting the `null` values to the end. And if you did not intend to answer, then your "answer" should be included in your "question", and not the section reserved for answers. Still a dup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106538/discussion-between-nishchit-dhanani-and-blakes-seven).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used a dirty hack for this.

MongoDB [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#ascending-descending-sort) says that they have priorities for sorting as posted below image.

[image]

So when i sort with **asc** then it sort first all **null** (empty key consider as null) entries then sort numeric entries.

**What is hack here ?**

Store `sr_no : ""` with empty string default.

Now it will sort first **numeric** values then **string**.

Comment: For which version this is working? I am unable to get on MongoDB 4

Comment: I don't think it is handling a case where sr_no is absent in a document.