# Sort only existing fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the collection like this.
Only a few users have `sortOrder` field

```
[{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c105",
    "name": "Best FX broker ",
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c102",
    "name": "Best automated Performance tool ",
    "sortOrder": 1,
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c104",
    "name": "Best Regtech/ reporting solution ",
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c106",
    "name": "NEW: BEST CRYPTO SERVICE PROVIDER",
    "sortOrder": 2,
}]
```

When I sort by `sort({"sortOrder": 1})` I get this

```
[{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c105",
    "name": "Best FX broker ",
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c104",
    "name": "Best Regtech/ reporting solution ",
},
{
   "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c102",
    "name": "Best automated Performance tool ",
    "sortOrder": 1,
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c106",
    "name": "NEW: BEST CRYPTO SERVICE PROVIDER",
    "sortOrder": 2,
}]
```

But I need to sort collection like this (values with field `sortOrder` at top)

```
[ {
   "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c102",
    "name": "Best automated Performance tool ",
    "sortOrder": 1,
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c106",
    "name": "NEW: BEST CRYPTO SERVICE PROVIDER",
    "sortOrder": 2,
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c105",
    "name": "Best FX broker ",
},
{
    "_id": "59ccf78bde3d14019169c104",
    "name": "Best Regtech/ reporting solution ",
}]
```

What query should I write to get this?

Comment: It doesn't look like your exact use case is supported, but there are some workarounds/other methods to possibly get you what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028267/mongodb-sort-by-only-exists-entry-key-with-value-first-and-key-with-null-or-not and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680809/mongodb-sort-by-field-existing-and-then-alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project : {"_id" : 1, "sortOrder" : 1,"name":1, "sortOrder": { "$ifNull": [ "$sortOrder", ""] }}},
{$sort : {sortOrder : 1}}   
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks to handle the sort to almost any way.

While my solution is disgustingly inefficient (sorry), it works:

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.sortOrder == undefined && b.sortOrder == undefined) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a.sortOrder == undefined) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b.sortOrder == undefined) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.sortOrder > b.sortOrder) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.sortOrder < b.sortOrder) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```

The a and b variables here are the elements in the array, and here returning -1 moves it to the front of the array, 0 doesn't change, 1 moves it back of the array, if that makes sense.